# Django does not store password in database

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, view

When i print my password from view it shows non in my command prompt
i am using only password1 in forms.py
i put pass2=none

**Models.py:-**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
            user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
            location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
            birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
            gender = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True)

            def __str__(self):
                return self.fullname
```

**Forms.py:-**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
            username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','placeholder': 'Enter Username'}))
            password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Password'}))
            email=forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter Email'}))
    password2=None


            class Meta:
                model=User
                fields=['username','password1','email']



        class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
            fullname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter fullname'}))
            class Meta:
                model=Profile
                fields=['fullname']
```

**views.py:-**

```
def register(request):
        if request.method =='POST':
            form = UserForm(request.POST)
            profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user=form.save()
                profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user=user
                profile.save()
                username= form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                password= form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                print(username)
                print(password)
                messages.success(request,f'account created for {{ username }}')
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = UserForm()
            profile_form = ProfileForm()
        context={'form':form , 'profile_form':profile_form}
        return render(request, 'users/register.html',context)
```

**When i print my password in viws it shows None.also i am using only password1 **

Comment: `password= form.cleaned_data.get('password')` -> `password= form.cleaned_data.get('password1')` Your field is called `password1` and you tried to get data from `password` field which doesn't exist.

Comment: @h4z3 i fixed it but it doesnt store data in database(i use mysql) and admin panel.

Comment: I believe because for the User model to validate the password, password1 and password2 must be equal.

Comment: @Aerials what if i dont provide password 2?

Comment: @RamPatil change the name of your password field in your form, from `password1` to just `password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem is your `UserForm`.

It is requiring the fields: `['username','password1','email']`
from the `User` model, as if they existed.

The `User` model **does NOT** have a field called `"password1"`. It does have a `"password"` field.

So if you change the fields in your `UserForm` `Meta` class to `['username','password','email']` and change the `UserForm` "password1" field as well it will work.

#### Now when you save the valid form, it will actually pass a field (`"password"`) to the `User model` which it needs in order to generate your hashed password.

Comment: Thank you.I fixed it by changing password1 to password.
In django form it shows password1 for normal password and password2 to re-enter the same.So i used  just password1.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the user module that comes with django.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Django for storing data in db.sqlite file in an encrypted format. You need a secret key to access while decoding which is present in settings.py file.you can decode all the data with it but not password

The passwords will be hashed in sha256 algorithm for 16 iterations so you cant get the password and this is done by default
If you want to reset the password use put call to reset it

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it solves your question

Comment: you do this                                                                                                                     u = User.objects.get(username__exact=username)
print u.password    (this gets you hashed user password) you cant view the password since its hashed

Comment: Thank you for commenting.I wrote password for password1.